# Cannot file.delete() and file.renameTo() for Java

Tags: java, file, delete-file, file-rename

I am currently making a `Jtable` that will display and update user data. When updating data, my code will generate a **temp.txt** file with the new data and then the old **Student_Database.txt** will be deleted and **temp.txt** will be renamed to **Student_Database.txt**. However, this not working, **temp.txt** is generated but the old **Student_Database.txt** is not deleted and the **temp.txt** is not renamed. I need guidance on how to fix it.

```
    String filepath = "Student_Database.txt";
    String temppath = "temp.txt";
    File oldfile = new File(filepath);
    File newfile = new File(temppath);

    assert (oldfile.exists());

    String id = "";
    String pass = "";
    String name = "";
    String email = "";
    String number = "";
    String number_intake = "";
    String number_degree = "";

    String user_id = userID_textfield.getText();
    String password = password_textfield.getText();
    String user_name = name_textfield.getText();
    String email_id = emailaddress_textfield.getText();
    String contact_number = contactnumber_textfield.getText();
    String intake_number = intakenumber_textfield.getText();
    String degree_level = degreelevel_textfield.getText();

    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newfile, true)));
        Scanner x = new Scanner(oldfile))
    {

        x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");


        while (x.hasNext())
        {

            id = x.next();
            pass = x.next();
            name = x.next();
            email = x.next();
            number = x.next();
            number_intake = x.next();
            number_degree = x.next();

            if (id.equals(user_id))
            {
                pw.print(user_id+ "," +password+ "," +user_name+ "," +email_id+ "," +contact_number+ "," +intake_number+ "," +degree_level+ "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                pw.print(id+ "," +pass+ "," +name+ "," +email+ "," +number+ "," +number_intake+ "," +number_degree);
            }
        }

        Files.move(newfile.toPath(), oldfile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Print Stack Trace.

java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Student_Database.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:384)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:292)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1424)
at GUIs.Student_Database_Menu.jButton2ActionPerformed(Student_Database_Menu.java:476)
at GUIs.Student_Database_Menu$4.actionPerformed(Student_Database_Menu.java:102)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Why do you have a catch to ignore what happens in it? Don't swallow exceptions. Maybe there is a legitimate exception/reason that file cannot be deleted.

Comment: In other words do not  `catch(Exception e)
        { 
        }`. Use  `catch(Exception e)
        {
      e.printStackTrace();
        }` and get useful error information.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: I try to convice him of that since a few hours, but seem to have no success with it. Maybe my answer isn't understandable enough.

Comment: you are trying to move the file while it is still open... move the `Files.move(...` statement outside the try block (as 'second' already commented), that is, after (and outside) the `catch` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try-with-resource (that closes the used resources automatically),
and afterward you can do the move operation.

You could try using the classes from the `java.nio` package instead.

(Also make sure that your file paths are correct and no other processes have opened the files)

Simplified example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filepath = "Student_Database.txt";
    String temppath = "temp.txt";
    File oldfile = new File(filepath);
    File newfile = new File(temppath);

    assert (oldfile.exists());
    
    try (
       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newfile, true)));
       Scanner x = new Scanner(oldfile)
    ) {

        x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

        int id = 0;
        while (x.hasNext())  {
            id = x.nextInt();
            pw.print(id + "\n");
        }

        pw.print(++id + "\n");
    
        // If you put the move here, it will fail as there 
        // are still active handles on the files.
    } catch (IOException e) {

       // add some logging 

    } // <--- this bracket is important, the move must be below.

    // At this point the try-with-resources guarantess 
    // that all previous openened handles (defined in the try-with) have been closed.

    // do move operation here
    try {
        Files.move(newfile.toPath(), oldfile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // add some more logging 
    }
}
```

I've added a simple example. The Student_Database.txt must exist and should initially be empty. Every execution of this will add a new line with an incremented id to the file.

Comment: I added a Println catch and it said this. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Student_Database.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. I added fw.flush() and fw.close() before pw.flush() and pw.close(). Sorry for asking alot of questions. Just starting to learn Java.

Comment: There is no other errors other than C:\Users\farid\Desktop\Consultation System V2\Student_Database.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. i am currently using e.getMessage() for the catch. Should i change to something else ?

Comment: I've update the example a bit. If the file is not opened by this, make sure your program has proper permissions and the file is not opened by anything else. // You might want to use e.printStackTrace(); instead

Comment: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@79ad6009 it says this now.

Comment: No need for a FileSystem object.  `Path source = newfile.toPath();` is sufficient.

Comment: Ok , so i changed my code , im still using try catch however i put the readers in a bracket beside catch because i cant edit GUI methods and im still using my current lines of code to update the data. i used all the new codes that you have shown. and I still get an error but the StackTrace is updated. Ill put the line errors in the main question area.

Comment: If that still doesn't help something else in your OS or code still holds an active reference to the file. You could use the 'Process Explorer' (for Windows) or a similiar tool to display which process holds a handle on your file.

Comment: Okay. You are still making the same mistaking of having the move operation in the same block as the work operation. Move it to the lines after the catch block (prepare its own try catch block if you must suppress the exception)

Comment: Updated my example with some more comments to point out the error more explicitly.

Comment: ok sorry, second but the error still comes out which is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement . Even when i did exactly as you said. I dont know if the problem is because of directory or something . But thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Well a Compilation Error is something different. I just check my example again, but it should compile just fine. Any IDE should mark the coressponding `catch block` or `method declaration` and you could just remove it. A compilation error is easier to work out, you might want to start a new question with that.

Comment: Not sure whether its related but I removed the `throws IOException` defined on my `main` method, when I edited in the `try catch` blocks.

Comment: Ill just try to go back to an earlier state and start from there. if i succeed ill let you know . Thanks alot man.